# Почему JS не подключился к HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Всё работало, но удалил какой то элемент в head станицы (сам появился, не помню что за он, может и не в нём дело) через консоль в инспекторе браузера. И теперь вроде всё верно, а js не видит? Что это за магия) Скрин с расположением файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И сам код:

```js
let buttonSendForm = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonSend');

buttonSendForm.onclick = () => {
  let user = makeUserObject();

  if (validateUser(user) == true) {
    delete user["repeatPassword"];
    sendDataForm(user);
  }
}

function makeUserObject() {
  let user = {};
  let fieldsForm = document.getElementsByClassName("field");
  let fieldsRadio = document.getElementsByClassName("fieldRadio");

  for (let i = 0; i < fieldsForm.length; i++) {
    let name = fieldsForm[i].name;
    let value = fieldsForm[i].value;
    user[name] = value;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < fieldsRadio.length; i++) {
    if (fieldsRadio[i].checked) {
      let name = fieldsRadio[i].name;
      let value = fieldsRadio[i].value;
      user[name] = value;
      break;
    }
  }

  return user;
}

function validateUser(user) {
  // regExp 
  let templateFullName = /^([a-zA-Z]+)$|^([а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)$/;
  let templateLoginAndPassword = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/;
  let templateEmail = /^[\w_.]{3,}@([a-z]{2,})\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

  let textErrors = document.getElementsByClassName("divInfo");
  let statusOperation = false;

  if (templateFullName.test(user.name) != true) {
    textErrors.innerHTML = "Name error";
  } else if (templateFullName.test(user.middleName) != true) {
    textErrors.innerHTML = "Error in middle name";
  } else if (templateFullName.test(user.lastName) != true) {
    textErrors.innerHTML = "Last name error";
  } else if (templateLoginAndPassword.test(user.login) != true) {
    textErrors.innerHTML = "Error in login";
  } else if (templateLoginAndPassword.test(user.password) != true) {
    textErrors.innerHTML = "Error in password";
  } else if (user.password != user.repeatPassword) {
    textErrors.innerHTML = "Passwords aren't the same";
  } else if (templateEmail.test(user.email) != true) {
    textErrors.innerHTML = "Error in email";
  } else {
    statusOperation = true;
    textErrors.innerHTML = "";
  }

  return statusOperation;
}

function sendDataForm(user) {
  let json = JSON.stringify(user);
  let infoLoad = document.getElementsByClassName("divInfo");

  /* Настройка AJAX запроса */
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/systempark/mainservlet");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  // xhr.setRequestHeader("Page-Client", "register");
  xhr.send(json);

  console.log("Sent json: " + json);

  /* Обработка ответа с сервера */
  xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log("Ответ сервера получен, статус - " + xhr.status);

    if (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304) {
      let resultOperation = Number(xhr.response);
      console.log("resultOperation = " + resultOperation);
      if (resultOperation === -1) {
        infoLoad.innerHTML = "Пользователь с таким логином или email существует!";
      } else if (resultOperation === 1) {
        alert("Ваш аккаунт создан! Нажмите ОК - для перехода на страницу входа");
        window.location.href = 'login.html';
      } else if (resultOperation === 0) {
        alert("Ошибка операции на сервере");
      }
    } else {
      alert("ERROR, status: " + xhr.status + ", statusText: " + xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Sign Up</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section id="sectionRegistration">
      <form id="formRegistration">
        <div class="paragraphForm">
          <label for="name"> Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="field"><br>
        </div>

        <div class="paragraphForm">
          <label for="middleName">Middle name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="middleName" id="middleName" class="field">
        </div>

        <p class="paragraphForm">
          <label for="lastName">Last name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="field">
        </p>

        <p class="paragraphForm">
          <label for="login">Desired Login:</label>
          <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="field">
        </p>

        <p class="paragraphForm">
          <label for="password">Desired Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="field">
        </p>

        <p class="paragraphForm">
          <label for="repeatPassword">REPEAT Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="repeatPassword" id="repeatPassword" class="field">
        </p>

        <p class="paragraphForm">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="field">
        </p>

        <p class="paragraphForm">
          Role:
          <label for="roleOwner"> OWNER </label>
          <input type="radio" name="role" value="owner" id="roleOwner" class="fieldRadio field">

          <label for="roleForester"> FORESTER </label>
          <input type="radio" name="role" value="forester" id="roleForester" checked class="fieldRadio field">
        </p>

      </form>

      <!--ОТПРАВИТЬ-->
      <input class="buttonSend" type="submit" name="sendForm" value="Sign Up" id="registerButton">

      <!--НАЗАД-->
      <div class="buttonBack"><a href="systemPark.html"> Return Back </a></div>

      <!--DIV с ошибками из формы-->
      <div class="divInfo"></div>

    </section>
  </main>

  <footer></footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/registration.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Как именно вы определяете, что не подключился?

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку - у меня должны появиться ошибки что поля пустые. 
Во вторых пробовал вызывать на странице JS console.log("с меткой"); дабы увидеть что происходит. Но срабатывает только один раз такой лог в самом начале js страницы и всё...сколько бы я не жал на кнопку, какие бы слушатели не добавлял (только один раз выводит лог и нету никаких ошибок)

Comment: Ну ваш скрипт в текущем его виде не добавляет никаких слушателей ни на какие кнопки, так что скрипт вполне может подключиться и просто ничего не сделать

Comment: buttonSendForm.onclick - это ведь и есть обработчик нажатия на кнопку? не слушатель, но обрабатывает нажатие

Comment: Неа, этот код просто добавляет свойство onclick в объект HTMLCollection, который не является кнопкой. А вот `buttonSendForm[0]` уже скорее всего будет кнопкой

Comment: хм, просто раньше это работало) сейчас открою посомтрю, может вы правы ...

Comment: Скорее всего раньше у вас работало getElementById, который возвращает не коллекцию, а непосредственно элемент

Comment: Да, я заметил что с событием недосомтрел, getElementsByClassName - не работает почему то на класс указанный в div. Спасибо большое)